# Handling business logic before and after saving entity

Tags: entity-framework

So before EF, I did something like this in the Save() method of Order

```
public void Save(){
    //validate
    if (this.OrderItems.Count == 0)
        throw new Exception ("You need at least one order item");

    //so the user code does not have to do this
    this.DateTimeModified = DateTime.Now;

    saveToDataBase();

    //after saving to the DB, the order amount is greater than $3000, notify certain people
    if (OrderAmount >= 3000)
        notifyPersonell();
}
```

As you can see above, everything was nicely encapsulated in Order.Save().

What is the most elegant way of doing this? Someone suggests putting all the stuff before saving in ValidateOrder() and stuff after in AfterOrderSaved(). That is absurd. So the user code will have to remember to do this.

```
order.ValidateOrder();
context.SaveChanges();
order.AfterOrderChanged();
```

That completely flies in the face of encapsulation. What if the user code forgets to call ValidateOrder and AfterOrderChanged?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Ermmm?? Most elegant way of doing something you're not going to do anymore? With EF you'll most certainly not have an `Order.Save` method.

Comment: Please elaborate.  Of course I am not going to have Order.Save any more in EF.  So how do I enforce the business rules I want to enforce before and after Order is saved?

Comment: You'd probably have some service method SaveOrder which does all that. But this is a rather broad question.

Comment: I was hoping it wasn't so broad.  Am I looking at it the wrong way?  Every time Order is saved, I want to enforce critical business rules before and after saving.